# C# MVC: Can we have partial update on the model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

We have c# model class with following fields:

```
public class BasicDetailsModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
}
```

Once user clicks on save button with (Name="x", Email="x@gmail.com", Mobile=989), these details get saved in database. Now, in case user updates any of these fields i.e. Name to "y", we have to send Email,Mobile too although these have not changed.

I have oversimplified the problem here. We have multiple cases where Models have over 20 fields and we are updating more than 5 models through single save click.

How can we update only what's needed and assure everything else already saved remain as it is i.e. in this case client would only send (Name="y") and Database will have (Name="y", Email="x@gmail.com", Mobile=989).

I don't want to make multiple database calls before saving and want flexibility that user remove value from already entered fields i.e. can change Name from "y" to null.

Comment: your editing data so you should always be using a view model. In the POST method you get the data model from the database and update only those properties you want from the view model.

Comment: @maverick, are you working directly with the model in frontend or you using view model?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: But even in view-model, even if user changes 1 property, we need to change all the models that are associated with that particular view model.

Comment: I assume you mean _all the properties_, and of course you do.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Yeah, property. But its a very big cost esp. when we have a very long form i.e. form with 50 properties that will bind to may be >5 models

Comment: What cost? your not seriously going to write stored procedures for every single combination of properties (10's of thousands of them). And for what - it makes no difference to performance

Comment: @StephenMuecke: But this is big problem with multi-step forms where user can have top/side navigation to move from one step to another. If we follow this, we will have to send back all the information at any step's next/save click. Check something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgZRS.png

Comment: Its not a problem at all. And I guarantee you that you will have far more bottleneck issues in your code than the extra millisecond (if that) you you could ever save. And if its a multi-step wizard, you will probably be saving each step separately anyway

Comment: @StephenMuecke: In this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgZRS.png, if user fills step1,2,3 by clicking Next (bottom right), and then move to step 1 by clicking on "Contact Details" tab at top left, then changes Name, move to step3 by clicking "Car Images", and then click next button on "Car Images" step, we will have to save step1, step2, step3 data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151711/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-maverick).